# Elasticsearch: how to delete entries based on match criteria

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do I delete certain documents based on the search criteria?

I am using ElasticSearch Java API.

I would like to delete the documents, which fall on matching criteria. How do I do this? I did not find it.

One option which I thought is to query with match criteria and then get Ids of each and delete them.

Here is the code to delete based on the id, which I am doing.

```
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders
            .boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("myid", "2"))
            .minimumShouldMatch("100%")
            .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("hnumber", "22"))
            .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);
    SearchResponse actionGet = client.prepareSearch(<index>).setTypes(<type>)
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)
            .addSort("timestamp", SortOrder.DESC)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .setFrom(0)
            .setSize(15)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

For each result, the following code is executed.

```
    Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(strIPAddress, iPort));
    try {
        DeleteResponse response = client.prepareDelete(<index>, <type>, id)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
        return response.getId();
    } catch(Throwable th){
    } finally {
        if(null != client) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
```

I would like to know how I can do without actually querying and delete with matching query. I see in Java API there is a method prepareDeleteByQuery, not sure how to use this.

Can you please help me out with this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder and execute,

I've managed to create request for you.

```
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder requestBuilder=new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(transportClient);
requestBuilder.setQuery(
                QueryBuilders
                        .boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("myid", "2"))
                        .minimumShouldMatch("100%")
                        .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("hnumber", "22"))
                        .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
        );
requestBuilder.get(); //it have the response
```

Hope this helps!! Thanks

Comment: how do I set index and type to the client. like in the example that I gave above has index and type.

Comment: use `requestBuilder.setIndices()` `requestBuilder.setTypes()` methods